# 27.5" x 3.0" tires?

Tags: tire

Last year, I acquired an [SE-Bikes Maniacc Flyer 27.5"+](https://www.sebikes.com/collections/bikelife-series/products/2021-maniacc-flyer-27-5). I live in Europe and now I have to replace one of the tires, the bike came with: `Vee Tire Co. x SE Racing Speedster, 27.5" x 3.0" Tires (yellow)` – I already though, that getting yellow ones was not going to be easy, but now, just getting any tire, with these dimensions and with no profile, or a similar one to the Speedster seems almost impossible. I can't find any… I already contacted VEE-Tire-Co.-Germany and they told me, they might be able to get them, but shipping alone would be about: 200,- EUR, I can't do that…

I don't need these exact tires, but **I need 27.5" x 3.0" tires**, with a pretty flat profile, or no profile. - Does anyone know a manufacturer that produces such tires?

Thank You! – Simon

Comment: Related: https://www.bikeradar.com/features/less-is-more-why-the-27-5-plus-standard-is-doomed/, https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/66246/replace-27-5-x-3-mtb-tires-with-27-5-x-2-1?rq=1

Comment: @ojs I feel these articles don't really apply to my situation, this is a BMX and not a Mountainbike. There are more than just a view kids out there riding wheelie bikes with 3.5" tires… Still, thank you, for your answer!

Comment: Ok, if the color must match then you're in trouble. I checked bike-components.de and they seem to have some selection of 27.5x around 3" semislicks in stock.

Comment: You would have a simpler task if you tried to find a 2.8'' tyre. In that case you could go with Maxxis Ikon+ 27.5x2.8'' with either dual or 3C MaxxSpeed compund. That is a semi-slick tyre that would do the job.
If you really need a 3.00''wide  tyre, the closest to your tyres that I can find is the Schwalbe Rocket Ron. That is also a low profile tyre so it might suit you fine.

Comment: Right now, I would be super happy, if I could just get black ones. I also, already, checked bike-components and there are a couple of 2.8" tires available, I might even be able to get the 2.8"-Speedsters, and if I can't get 3.0", that's probably what I will ride for a while, but I really like the 3.0"-tires and I'd like to continue riding tires of that width…

Comment: @Mick Thank you, for your answer! – I know, there are 3.00" MTB-tires, but that's not going to work, looks like I will have to ride 2.8" for now…

Edit: The Rocket Ron has to much profile, for what I want to do…

Comment: Sorry - this question is shopping, pure and simple.  You can either go to a Local Bike Shop and see what's available, or try a web-based store. You have all the numbers needed to filter down on eligible 27.5" tyres for your MTB in about 3" wide, and photos will show you the tread.  Closing as "off topic" please don't take it personally.

Comment: No hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

How about Schwalbe G-One Allround, performance line, 2.8" wide?

Size:
ETRTO 70-584 (27.5 x 2.80Inch)
Typ:
Folding
Compound:
ADDIX
Execution:
DD, RaceGuard
Color:
Black
Seal:
TLE
Weight:
845 g
Pressure:
1.50 - 3.00 Bar (20 - 45psi)
Maximum load:
150 kg
EPI:
67
E-bike:
E-25
Profil:
HS473
Article number:
11600953.01
EAN:
4026495885362

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! The G-Ones look solid, but I would like to continue riding 3.0"…

Comment: @SimonR. In my experience, a 2.8" tire and a 3.0" are functionally equivalent, especially when comparing across brands. Schwalbe, again in my experience, tend to be one of the wider brands for a given nominal width. (e.g., a Maxxis 2.8" tire is as wide as a Schwalbe 2.35" tire)

Comment: @PaulH Wait, if I buy 2.8" tires from multiple different brands, they will not all be the same width?

Comment: They are supossed to be same width, i.e. the stated width, but, dissapointingly, they are not. Having used several models of Maxxis 2.8'' tyres, I can say that they are usually a little narrower than stated, measuring about 2.6''. Schwalbes are said to be a little wider than stated (haven't used any yet so I can't say myself). To determine the actual width of your tyre, simply measure it using a ruler or a caliper.

Comment: @Mick Agree completely. In my observation, which is limited to Maxxis and Schwalbe tires mounted on rims with 30 mm and 35 mm widths, it _appears_ that Maxxis is reporting the width of the widest knobs (good for communicating clearance through frames and forks) and Schwalbe is reporting the width of the casing (good for comparing tire volumes).

Comment: @SimonR. correct. If you think about, even without an perverse incentives to fudge the numbers to gain an edge on weight or volume/performance, constructing two different tires where the casing is *exactly* the same width as intended on any width of rim, is very difficult. Similarly, The difference between a 2.8" and 3.0" inch tire is 0.1" on each side. Given the variability in tires and rim widths, I consider the sizes functionally equivalent when it comes to e.g.,  bottom bracket height.

Comment: Oh, this is very interesting, I did not consider this… Well I just ordered some `Schwalbe Super Moto-X` tires, I wish I could get yellow ones, but they look really solid and Schwalbe-tires have worked well for me in the past, so I very much look forward to riding them. Thanks everyone! :)